# SharePoint 2007 - Copy files and assign attributes?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've got this one thing I'm not really sure where to begin with. In our SharePoint 2007 solution, we've got this project room where each employee has their own folders with their resumé etc. And we want this information to be distributed to their MySite.

I've noticed that I can basically copy the files from one are to the other. But the files in MySite are connected to the corresponding user based on properties of some sort. But they are not regular file properties is seems. When I open all of the files in the MySite files collection, I can see categories such as Title and Name. If I copy a file in there, these properties are blank. And if I manually assign a username to the Name property, the file automatically appears in the correct user's MySite.

Probably horribly explained.. But, is it possible to program this somehow? I would like a nightly or weekly schedule that basically copies the content and assigns the username and title to the correct fields. I can pick up both the title and the username based on the folder names. This I can probably solve later. It's just where to begin that's bothering me. Do I use SharePoint designer? Can I user VB code? Do I have to code at all? I've never developed a thing for SharePoint before. And no, I do not want to be redirected to a basic "Getting started with developing for Sharepoint" site.. Just a simple answer really, on where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Yes you can use VB. Create Timerjobs.

TimerJobs you can set to start on specific weekdays, specific hours etc. and they do exactly whatever you program them to do.

Comment: Aha that sounds promising :) What do I use to program this? SharePoint Designer or? I'm not quite sure how this all works in Sharepoint.

Comment: @Kenny SharePoint Designer is a configuration tool, so no :( To program timerjobs you need MS Visual Studio. But I can tell you right away that it is not simple nor easy to program for SharePoint.